# Is there a way to make the QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName as conditional in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

So in my code, I have the simple getSaveFileName dialog which looks like this:

```
saveFileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File","/some/file/directory/")
```

In the dialog if you try and overwrite a file, the dialog prompts a message box along the lines of "Are you sure you want to rewrite" BEFORE the dialog closes. I want to implement the same thing but with a different condition. I want to check if the file is in a specific location and if it is, I want to make it throw an error with a yes | no question, and the result is the same as when the overwrite message came up. Is there a way to implement this BEFORE the dialog closes? I already have a way to do it AFTER it closes but that's just not right...

Comment: You'll have to subclass `QFileDialog` rather than use the convenience function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
class D(QtGui.QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QFileDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        self.currentChanged.connect(self.check_first)
        for bb in self.children():
            if bb.__class__ == QtGui.QDialogButtonBox:
                self.OK = bb.buttons()[0]
            if bb.__class__ == QtGui.QLineEdit:
                bb.textChanged.connect(self.check_first)

    def check_first(self, filestring):
        print "check"
        if os.path.exists(self.selectedFiles()[0]):
            self.OK.setEnabled(True)
            print "OK"
        else:
            self.OK.setEnabled(False)
            print "Not OK"
```

You can put your own check into check_first, in this case the file's existence. I couldn't find a better way of locating the child widgets than comparing classes, but this seems to work.